# Iterating through a nested yaml document in Python

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a nested Yaml like this that I want to iterate thru and create a list of objects from .

```
---
InternalRuleService:
  - HomeRules:
    - RuleName: Sample1
      IgnoreList:
      InputParameters:
      - resourceId: some-res-id
      - ruleAge: 1
      - ruleAgeUnits: days
    - RuleName: Sample2
      IgnoreList:
      - Account: '12'
        Region: NorthAmericas
      - Account: '10'
        Region: AsiaPacific
      - Account: '10'
        Region: Europe
      InputParameters:
      - InterfaceIds: xxxx1,xxxxx2
    - RuleName: Sample3
      IgnoreList:
      - Account: '14'
        Region: NorthAmericas
      - Account: '18'
        Region: MiddleEast
      InputParameters:
      - localContact: JohnDoe
        contactNumber: 123123 
  - CustomRules:
    - RuleName: CustomOne
      documentType: packet
      IgnoreList: 
      - Account: '14'
        Region: NorthAmericas
      - Account: '18'
        Region: MiddleEast
ThirdPartyRules:
  - RuleName: alta-prism
    licenseType: multi
    licenseAge: 5
    licenseAgeUnit: year
    IgnoreList: 
      - Account: '45'
        Region: NorthAmericas
      - Account: '44'
        Region: MiddleEast
```

This is my code

```
import yaml
import json 

with open('rules.yml', 'r') as file:
   rules = yaml.safe_load(file)
    
for rows in rules:
   print(rows)
```

This gives only `InternalRuleService` and `ThirdPartyRules` in the output.
I want to iterate through all the HomeRules and tried this

```
for rows in rules:
    print(rows['HomeRules'])
```

which gave me the error below

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

This is what I am trying with the indices

```
for rows in rules:
    print(rows[0])
```

This results in the I and T being printed on the screen. How do you access each item in this yaml and build a python object from it? The object I wanted from this Yaml file is one with properties as below

> RuleName, IgnoreList`<LIST>`,InputParameters`<LIST>`,RuleType,SubRuleType

Here RuleType will be `InternalRuleService` and `ThirdPartyRules`, while SubRuleType will be `HomeRules` and `CustomRules` for only those cases where RuleType will be `InternalRuleService`.
Ignore

Answer (score 1):

Because of the minus in front of `HomeRules` and `CustomRules`, `InternalRuleService` becomes a list, not a dict. Therefore you need the int indicies.

This can be quickly determined with pprint:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(rules, depth=3)
{'InternalRuleService': [{'HomeRules': [...]}, {'CustomRules': [...]}],
 'ThirdPartyRules': [{'IgnoreList': [...],
                      'RuleName': 'alta-prism',
                      'licenseAge': 5,
                      'licenseAgeUnit': 'year',
                      'licenseType': 'multi'}]}
```

---

To iterate `HomeRules` from the current yaml you have can do:

```py
for rows in rules['InternalRuleService'][0]['HomeRules']:
   print(rows)
```

which prints

```
{'RuleName': 'Sample1', 'IgnoreList': None, 'InputParameters': [{'resourceId': 'some-res-id'}, {'ruleAge': 1}, {'ruleAgeUnits': 'days'}]}
{'RuleName': 'Sample2', 'IgnoreList': [{'Account': '12', 'Region': 'NorthAmericas'}, {'Account': '10', 'Region': 'AsiaPacific'}, {'Account': '10', 'Region': 'Europe'}], 'InputParameters': [{'InterfaceIds': 'xxxx1,xxxxx2'}]}
{'RuleName': 'Sample3', 'IgnoreList': [{'Account': '14', 'Region': 'NorthAmericas'}, {'Account': '18', 'Region': 'MiddleEast'}], 'InputParameters': [{'localContact': 'JohnDoe', 'contactNumber': 123123}]}
```

If you remove the `-`  before `HomeRules` and `CustomRules` you can remove the list-item index `[0]` and just write:

```py
for rows in rules['InternalRuleService']['HomeRules']:
   print(rows)
```